# Curl in python program

Tags: python, json, curl, urllib

I'm using **urllib** in order to get the output of multiple curls. All the outputs are JSON and I have an array with all I need to correctly use curl:

```
for i in array:
     url='http://example/' + i +'/example2'
     urllib.urlretrieve(url,'data.json')
     with open("data.json") as file:
     data=json.load(file)
```

inside this loop, I also write to a **csv** file all the data retrieved from the JSON file to save the data.

The problem is this gives an error whenever I try to call `urllib.urlretrieve()` the second time, the data.json file gets full of garbage characters. If I just call that code once it runs perfectly, however if I try to run it in a loop or in a sequence like:

```
url='http://example/' + array[0] +'/example2'
urllib.urlretrieve(url,'data.json')
with open("data.json") as file
data=json.load(file)

url='http://example/' + array[1] +'/example2'
urllib.urlretrieve(url,'data.json')
with open("data.json") as file:
data=json.load(file)
```

the file gets corrupted and it isn't considered a JSON by `json.load()`. Do anyone know what is my problem here?

EDIT: The error is : `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` Thats because the second 'data.json' becomes corrupted and it isn't considered a JSON file.

The second output of data.json seems to have the html code of the page.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) lib

Comment: Anyway, would be useful if you post here the return of request, JSON response.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Write it: filename, headers = urllib.urlretrieve(...). The headers will contain the http headers of the response, and say us what are you getting.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi  take a look at edit, thanks.

Comment: @luislhl edit,thanks

Comment: Have you access to the code that answers JSON? Perhaps, you must fix this (answer) code